# To gain ground: Synonym

Tags: synonyms, idiom-requests

What is the right synonym to describe that a scientific field gained ground?

My ideas:

- The field progressed/made progress
- The field evolved rapidly
- The field experienced an upswing

Do these convey the idea of something happening quickly/suddenly?

Comment: Can you define what exactly you mean with "gain ground" in this example and how it would look like for a field

Comment: @dubious, not really. I would like to convey a general idea of progress/development without further specification (if that is meant by gaining ground)

Comment: It's not clear what "scientific field gaining ground" means. Is that your question? Are you looking to define this phrase or are you looking for ways to rephrase it?

Comment: @dubious I want to rephrase it which implies that I need to understand what it exactly means

Comment: "evolved" suggests change but not necessarily progress - e.g. if it changed focus from one area to another or started using a different approach. Question is still a bit too vague - what sort of development are we talking about? And how formal? You could use e.g. "blew up" in less formal contexts.

Comment: @StuartF a development that refers to the number of practicing people

Comment: _gained currency_, although I'm not entirely sure if a *field* could be said to *gain currency.* Said mostly of ideas, notions, trends, etc. Meaning of the phrase per _Cambridge Dictionary_:
*to become more commonly known or accepted, or to start to be used in more and more places*.

Comment: @user405662 thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for something that means 'created more knowledge, progressed in understanding'? Or do you want 'became more widely known or gained more practitioners'?

Comment: 'Great progress was made in the field of bacteriology'. It's the scientists / man in general who gain ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gain-ground) "gain ground" means:

> [...] (become) more popular or accepted

"a scientific field gained ground" would then not match any of the provided examples. A correct rephrasing would be:

- a scientific field became more popular
- a scientific field became more accepted

Answer (score 7):

> The fields of mathematical physics and geometry **advanced** significantly thanks to the work of Felix Klein.

**advance** (v.)

> *Transitive*. To promote or help the progress, success, or completion of (something); to further.
>
> **1954** Further retrospective studies of that same kind would seem to us unlikely to **advance** our knowledge.
> *British Medical Journal* 26 June 1451/1
>
> *Intransitive*. To move or go forward, esp. in a purposeful way; to proceed.
> [OED online]

> (*v.t.*) To aid the growth or progress of: ***advanced** the cause of
> freedom*.
>
> (*v.intr.*) To make progress; improve.
> [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=advance)

> [ I or T ]
> To go or move something forward, or to develop or improve
> something
>
> *We have **advanced** greatly in our knowledge of the universe.*
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/advance)

---

> German mathematician FELIX KLEIN (1849-1925), a great teacher and
> scientific thinker, significantly **advanced the field of mathematical
> physics** and made a number of profound discoveries in the field of
> geometry.
> [Blurb for Felix Klein; *Elementary Mathematics from an
> Advanced Standpoint*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vfSutjEIZXkC&pg=PA277&dq=%22advanced%20the%20field%20of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzr9ijl92EAxU8FFkFHTDtDugQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=%22advanced%20the%20field%20of%22&f=false) (1939)

> The sum effort of these organizations has **advanced the field**
> significantly, creating a new discipline and changing the field to
> include a public health approach from a previously low-profile
> interest  of farm safety in agricultural colleges.
> [Kelley Donham and
> Anders Thelin; *Agricultural Medicine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hi_fCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT88&dq=%22advanced%20the%20field%20of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzr9ijl92EAxU8FFkFHTDtDugQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22advanced%20the%20field%20of%22&f=false) (2016)

> Islamic scholars made significant contributions to astronomy and
> cosmology during the Islamic Golden Age. Al-Battani, Al-Farabi, and
> Ibn al-Haytham were among those who **advanced astronomical knowledge**.
> [Arnoud Varens; *Astronomy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lODYEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&dq=astronomy%20advanced%20when%20the%20geocentric%20model&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNyMiytN2EAxWWFmIAHZaZA4w4ChDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=astronomy%20advanced%20when%20the%20geocentric%20model&f=false) (2023)

> Primitive societies that did not have archives of their past could not
> **advance beyond the knowledge that could be remembered**, and they tended not to **advance** to a sophisticated state.
> [Robert Grover et
> al.; *Assessing Information Needs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PnfDEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&dq=knowledge%20can%20advance%20beyond%20the%20primitive&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN_pqk_N2EAxVRKFkFHc1pAxUQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=knowledge%20can%20advance%20beyond%20the%20primitive&f=false) (2010)

Whether or not progress is "sudden" is relative. The publication of Gödel's incompleteness theorems and the structure of DNA were sudden events of great import. However, the lifetime work of one person (e.g. Gregor Mendel) can advance a field considerably after centuries of stagnation and may be viewed as sudden or revolutionary from the historical perspective.

Comment: great - thanks a lot! However, I think that the word 'advancement' implies someone who advances or something that is advanced. 
Saying 'a scientific field advanced (f.e. in the 13th century)' might raise the question in what sense the advancement took place.

Comment: @Sylvia I've added an example where *advance* is used with reference to the Islamic Golden Age (the 8th to the 13th century). It's simply to *make progress in a relative way*, to *improve*. Physicists may *advance* our knowledge about harnessing fusion to produce energy, but the field is in its infancy, not an *advance**d*** stage